# Multiple definitions of a function, first defined here

Tags: c, definition

I'm working on a scanner/parser for a university project, and I've run into this error:

> stack.c 91: multiple definition of '[all functions in stack.c]' 
>   stack.c 91: first defined here

For some reason that I can't seem to figure out the compiler seems to be telling me that I've defined the same function multiple times in the same place.

I was given some skeleton code and a makefile to start off with so there must be some sort of incorrect communication between the files I wrote entirely myself (stack.c, stack.h) and the rest of the code.

- makefile: http://pastebin.com/0Tx1Wixg
- symtab.c: http://pastebin.com/M5gg0b3n
- symtab.h: http://pastebin.com/NvkZdWTy
- stack.h: http://pastebin.com/qT8fXEK0
- stack.c: http://pastebin.com/FfPa06ys

I've been moving around #includes and messing with the makefile for over an hour now and just running into more and more issues. How should this be set up?

`stack.c` and `stack.h` are small files I wrote to be used in `symtab.c` and `symtab.h`.

Comment: Have you tried putting a guard in your header file to avoid multiple definitions?

Comment: I have pasted a new version of `stack.h` as http://pastebin.com/pxTVFJMM . Please try with this version and share your results?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685439/multiple-definition-of-c-compiler-error

Comment: @Ganest I tried adding that guard and still get the same result.

Answer (score 5):

In `symtab.h`, you are `#include`ing the source file `stack.c`. Don't do that, and that multiple definition problem should go away.

Comment: If I don't include stack.c then I get errors relating to the types defined in stack.c and stack.h which are used in symtab.h and symtab.c

Comment: @user1743798: You should not include source files in header files. You should not include source files in source files. You can include header files in header files, but make sure they are properly guarded against multiple inclusion.

Comment: I've edited my files as you suggested (always wondered what should include what, thanks) but my symtab.h now complains about types defined in stack.h and stack.c.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got things to (seemingly) work. As user315052 I removed all #includes from .h files and put them in .c files instead. I was then receiving errors from symtab.h about types defined in stack.h so I #included stack.h in symtab.h and it seems to now work (or at least compile).

Comment: You don't have to remove #includes from header files. Rule 1) put guards around all header files (or just use #pragma once -- everyone honors that these days). Rule 2) In each file, header or source, include the header files that define the types or other globals used by that file. That's logical, it works and is the right way per various principles of software composition.