# Gsoap compilation

Tags: c++, c, gsoap

I am trying to write a simple hello world gsoap sample. I have included the `http_get` plugin also. When i compile using :

```
g++ RestService.cpp soapC.cpp soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp -o server.exe -lgsoap++
```

I get the follwing errors :

```
    soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `soap_encode_string'
/tmp/cci3TH4N.o:RestService.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cc9vrCVB.o: In function `soap_decode_string':
soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp:(.text+0x138): multiple definition of `soap_decode_string'
/tmp/cci3TH4N.o:RestService.cpp:(.text+0x138): first defined here
/tmp/cc9vrCVB.o: In function `http_get':
soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp:(.text+0x162c): multiple definition of `http_get'
/tmp/cci3TH4N.o:RestService.cpp:(.text+0x5fe): first defined here
/tmp/cc9vrCVB.o: In function `query_val':
soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp:(.text+0x141a): multiple definition of `query_val'
/tmp/cci3TH4N.o:RestService.cpp:(.text+0x3ec): first defined here
/tmp/cc9vrCVB.o: In function `query_key':
soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp:(.text+0x148e): multiple definition of `query_key'
/tmp/cci3TH4N.o:RestService.cpp:(.text+0x460): first defined here
/tmp/cc9vrCVB.o: In function `query':
soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp:(.text+0x150c): multiple definition of `query'
/tmp/cci3TH4N.o:RestService.cpp:(.text+0x4de): first defined here
/tmp/cc9vrCVB.o: In function `soap_get_connect':
soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp:(.text+0x152c): multiple definition of `soap_get_connect'
/tmp/cci3TH4N.o:RestService.cpp:(.text+0x4fe): first defined here
/tmp/cc9vrCVB.o:(.rodata+0xc7): multiple definition of `http_get_id'
/tmp/cci3TH4N.o:(.rodata+0x13): first defined here
```

below is my code

```
#define soapRestServiceSoap12Service_H
#include "soapH.h"
#include "httpget.h"
#include "httpget.c"
class SOAP_CMAC RestServiceSoap12Service : public soap
{ public:
        /// Constructor
        RestServiceSoap12Service();
        /// Constructor with copy of another engine state
        RestServiceSoap12Service(const struct soap&);
        /// Constructor with engine input+output mode control
        RestServiceSoap12Service(soap_mode iomode);
        /// Constructor with engine input and output mode control
        RestServiceSoap12Service(soap_mode imode, soap_mode omode);
        /// Destructor frees all data
        virtual ~RestServiceSoap12Service();
        /// Initializer used by constructor
        virtual void RestServiceSoap12Service_init(soap_mode imode, soap_mode omode);
        /// Create a copy
        virtual RestServiceSoap12Service *copy();
        /// Force close connection (normally automatic)
        virtual int soap_close_socket();
        /// Return sender-related fault to sender
        virtual int soap_senderfault(const char *string, const char *detailXML);
        /// Return sender-related fault with SOAP 1.2 subcode to sender
        virtual int soap_senderfault(const char *subcodeQName, const char *string, const char *detailXML);
        /// Return receiver-related fault to sender
        virtual int soap_receiverfault(const char *string, const char *detailXML);
        /// Return receiver-related fault with SOAP 1.2 subcode to sender
        virtual int soap_receiverfault(const char *subcodeQName, const char *string, const char *detailXML);
        /// Print fault
        virtual void soap_print_fault(FILE*);
#ifndef WITH_LEAN
        /// Print fault to stream
        virtual void soap_stream_fault(std::ostream&);
 /// Put fault into buffer
        virtual char *soap_sprint_fault(char *buf, size_t len);
#endif
        /// Disables and removes SOAP Header from message
        virtual void soap_noheader();
        /// Run simple single-thread iterative service on port until a connection error occurs (returns error code or SOAP_OK), use this->bind_flag = SO_REUSEADDR to rebind for a rerun
        virtual int run(int port);
        /// Bind service to port (returns master socket or SOAP_INVALID_SOCKET)
        virtual SOAP_SOCKET bind(const char *host, int port, int backlog);
        /// Accept next request (returns socket or SOAP_INVALID_SOCKET)
        virtual SOAP_SOCKET accept();
        /// Serve this request (returns error code or SOAP_OK)
        virtual int serve();
        /// Used by serve() to dispatch a request (returns error code or SOAP_OK)
        virtual int dispatch();
        ///
        /// Service operations (you should define these):
        ///

        /// Web service operation 'HelloWorld' (returns error code or SOAP_OK)
        virtual int HelloWorld(_ns1__HelloWorld *ns1__HelloWorld, _ns1__HelloWorldResponse *ns1__HelloWorldResponse);

        /// Web service operation 'OpenAccountBalanceInquiry' (returns error code or SOAP_OK)
        virtual int OpenAccountBalanceInquiry(_ns1__OpenAccountBalanceInquiry *ns1__OpenAccountBalanceInquiry, _ns1__OpenAccountBalanceInquiryResponse *ns1__OpenAccountBalanceInquiryResponse);
        ///HTTP Get Handler
        //virtual int http_get_handler(soap *_soap);

        int Execute();


        private:
        struct soap objSoap;

};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that both `RestService.cpp` and `soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp` has `#include soapRestServiceSoap12Service.h` in their header so you have a double definition of some functions in `httpget.c`. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685439/multiple-definition-of-c-compiler-error) for a similar issue.

It is a good practice not to include `.cpp` or `.c` files in header files. I guess you can try to remove the `#include "httpget.c"` in `soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp` and then in your compilation, just add `httpget.c` source file.

e.g.

```
g++ httpget.c RestService.cpp soapC.cpp soapRestServiceSoap12Service.cpp -o server.exe -lgsoap++
```